# swiftui why can't optional be assigned?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why can't optional be assigned?

Index has been allocated, but still no value is displayed

Help me, Thank you!

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var index: Int? = nil
    @State private var show: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.index = 1
                    self.show = true
                    print(self.index as Any)
                }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $show) {
            if let index = self.index {
                Text("value:\(index)")
            } else {
                Text("not value")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode Version 12.0 beta 2

Comment: `if self.index != nil` don't do this, learn about conditional biding, `if let index = self.index { ... }`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica But can you do that in a closure in a SwiftUI View?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thanks,  I tried if unwrapping, but index not value, confused!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Good point, I remember there being issues about that. Didn't they resolve it, though?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica At least not in Xcode 11, I haven't tested Xcode 12/SwiftUI  2.0 yet.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Nothing to do with the Optional. Same thing if `index` is a simple Int.

Answer (score 6):

SwiftUI relies upon the `@State` variable causing the `body` getter to be recalculated when it changes. For this to work, the `body` getter must *depend* in certain definite ways on the `@State` variable. The problem in your code is that it doesn't.

To see this, we can reduce your code to a simpler example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var message = "Hey"
    @State var show: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Test") {
                message = "Ho"
                show = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $show) {Text(message)}
    }
}
```

We change `message` to Ho, but when the sheet is presented, it still says Hey. This is because nothing happened to make the `body` recalculate. You might say: What about the phrase `Text(message)`? Yes, but that's in a closure; it has already been calculated, and `message` has already been captured.

To see that what I'm saying is right, just add a Text displaying `message` directly to the main interface:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var message = "Hey"
    @State var show: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Test") {
                message = "Ho"
                show = true
            }
            Text(message)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $show) {Text(message)}
    }
}
```

Now your code works! Of course, we are also displaying an unwanted Text in the interface, but the point is, that plain and simple `Text(message)`, *not* in a closure, is sufficient to cause the whole `body` getter to be recalculated when `message` changes. So we have correctly explained the phenomenon you're asking about.

So what's the *real* solution? How can we get the `content` closure to operate as we expect *without* adding an extra Text to the interface? One way is like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var message = "Hey"
    @State var show: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Test") {
                message = "Ho"
                show = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $show) {[message] in Text(message)}
    }
}
```

By including `message` in the capture list for our closure, we make the `body` getter depend on the `message` variable, and now the code behaves as desired.

Comment: Perfect!, Great!, Thank You!